# Privacy error using pythonanywhere ssl certificate

Tags: python, ssl, https, payment-gateway, pythonanywhere

I have a [payment gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584432/forbidden-403-error-when-calling-the-callback-url-in-django/65598603?noredirect=1#comment116209362_65598603) in my web-app that requires an `SSL` certificate to work properly.

the web-app is a django web-app hosted at `pythonanywhere`. I used their `Auto-renewing Let's Encrypt certificate` to add an SSL certificate and make the website load as an `HTTPS` website.

The website now loads as an `HTTPS` website but when exiting the payment gateway I still get a Privacy error as follows

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from <my domain> (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

**[EDIT-1]**

1. I am using a custom domain that I bought from GoDaddy
2. I followed this [link](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/HTTPSSetup) to setup the SSL certificate
3. I have also enabled [forcing-https](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ForcingHTTPS) in pythonanywhere.
4. I changed the callback url in my views from `http://<my_domain>.org/payment/status/` to `https://<my_domain>.org/payment/status/`
5. The callback url page does not contain any http links. Just a css file as follows `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/paymentstatus.css' %}">`

Please note that when I visit the website, it shows as `https`. It is only when calling the callback URL does it return the Privacy error.

I did not face this error when I tried it in my local system with `ngrok`. This error occurs only with `pythonanywhere`.

**[EDIT-2]**

**`nslookup mydomain.org`**

```
▶ nslookup mydomain.org
Server:     2405:201:e011:3804::c0a8:1d01
Address:    2405:201:e011:3804::c0a8:1d01#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mydomain.org
Address: IP_ADDRESS
```

**`dig mydomain.org`**

```
▶ dig mydomain.org
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> mydomain.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8056
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.org.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.org.   225 IN  A   IP_ADDRESS

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 2405:201:e011:3804::c0a8:1d01#53(2405:201:e011:3804::c0a8:1d01)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 15 14:18:23 IST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

**[EDIT-3]**

I changed the url from `https://<my_domain>.org/` to `https://www.<my_domain>.org/`. This leads to a 404 error. I have added my views.py and url.py below

**views.py**

```
def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DonateForm(request.POST)

        name = request.POST.get('firstName')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        amount = float("{0:.2f}".format(int(request.POST.get('amount'))))
        ord_id = OrdID()
        cust_id = CustID()

        paytm_params = {
            "MID" : MERCHANTID,
            "WEBSITE" : "DEFAULT",
            "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" : "Retail",
            "CHANNEL_ID" : "WEB",
            "ORDER_ID" : ord_id,
            "CUST_ID" : cust_id,
            "MOBILE_NO" : phone,
            "EMAIL" : email,
            "TXN_AMOUNT" : str(amount),
            "CALLBACK_URL" : "https://www.<my_domain>.org/payment/status/",

            }

        paytm_params['CHECKSUMHASH'] = Checksum.generate_checksum(paytm_params, MERCHANTKEY)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return render(request, 'paytm.html', {'paytm_params': paytm_params})

    else:
        form = DonateForm()
        context = {'Donate': form}
        return render(request, 'donate.html', context=context)

@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = request.POST
        response_dict = {}

        for i in form.keys():
            response_dict[i] = form[i]

            if i == 'CHECKSUMHASH':
                checksum = form[i]
                print(checksum)

        verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANTKEY, checksum)

        if verify:
            if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
                print('order successful')
            else:
                print('error: ' + response_dict['RESPMSG'])

        return render(request, 'paymentstatus.html', {'response': response_dict})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    ...

    path('donate', views.donate, name='donate'),
    path('payment/status', views.handlerequest, name='handlerequest'),

    ...
]
```

#### [SOLUTION]

Firstly the `www.` to the url as the answer indicates was the issue. The 404 error was solved like this.

turns out the path in views and the path in urls should be the same. This solved the issue for me.

```
def donate(request):

    ...

    paytm_params = {
            "MID" : MERCHANTID,
            "WEBSITE" : "DEFAULT",
            "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" : "Retail",
            "CHANNEL_ID" : "WEB",
            "ORDER_ID" : ord_id,
            "CUST_ID" : cust_id,
            "MOBILE_NO" : phone,
            "EMAIL" : email,
            "TXN_AMOUNT" : str(amount),
            "CALLBACK_URL" : "https://www.<my_domain>.org/payment/status",
    
    ...
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    ...

    path('donate', views.donate, name='donate'),
    path('payment/status', views.handlerequest, name='handlerequest'),

    ...
]
```

Note that in the urls.py the path is as follows `payment/status`. Previously in views the path had a slash in the end like this `https://www.<my_domain>.org/payment/status/`. Removing the slash in the end worked for me.

Comment: Break it down please, how did you set up let's encrypt service? and what web server you used!

Comment: @AhmedShehab I have edited the question. Please take a look. Thanks again

Comment: check inside your static files if you load any image or svg from outer source that is not https

Comment: BTW, It might be something very simple that you misconfigured some parameters in your payment provider's dashboard, go through your configuration again.

Comment: Try to turn off force https from pythonanywhere and test again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is set up on PythonAnywhere, it's probably at `https://www.<my_domain>.org/`, not `https://<my_domain>.org/`.  So if your callback URL does not include the `www.` at the start, then try adding it and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. This seems to solve the issue. But this leads to a 404 error. I checked the `urls.py`. I dont think there is a problem with any of the paths. I have edited the question to add the `views.py` code and `urls.py` code. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

#### I will just guess now:

- either the DNS needs some time to propagate with the payment provider DNS database

inside terminal

```sh
# check NS record
nslookup yourdomain.org
# try to force refresh for few times
dig yourdomain.org
```

please share the output

- or what concerns me the most that you are using CDN service or loading assets served on http inside your https
- in the browser to left hit on the lock icon and check the certificate and if everything looks good you gotta get in touch with their support again to force refresh their DNS, normally it takes sometime to work automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are no images on the callback_url page. Just some basic styling like color and font.

Comment: I have edited the question to post the result of the `nslookup` and `dig` commands

Comment: Hi! do you know what is wrong with my program?

Comment: in the browser to left hit on the lock icon and check the certificate and if everything looks good you gotta get in touch with their support again with screen shot of the valid certificate and ask them to force refresh their DNS, normally it takes sometime to work automatically. As far as I believe you did your thing right as long as you can see valid cert in a browser, they might restrict some kind of A record or something else they can only answer you.

Comment: When I click the lock icon, it says `the connection is secure`. And the certificate is valid

Comment: When you say DNS refresh takes some time to refresh automatically, how long will that be? it is very difficult to get in touch with their technical team. There is no chat option, I have to send them an email which they don't respond to half the time. when they do respond, I have to explain the problem to them by mail and then they give the number to contact. This usually takes around a week, provided they respond.

Comment: Personally, I would try to mock the request and see what's happening, fake a post request with postman and check the outcome.

Comment: Can you explain in detail. As I said I am not too tech-savvy and still learning a lot about this

Comment: How did this work from my local system with ngrok? Why is it failing only with pythonanywhere

Comment: DNS propagation is very tied to the provider, normally it takes 5 minutes, but some providers the flush their DNS every 2 hrs or 24 hrs and worst cases is 96 hrs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227383/discussion-between-ahmed-shehab-and-sashaank).